# What happens when you run class_eval on something that's not a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

```
test = "a"
test.class_eval do
  # what is going on here???
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveSupport adds `class_eval` to Object so it can be used on anything, not just classes.

In your example, what it does is the equivalent of:

```
test = "a"
class << test
  # do stuff
end
```

The actual implementation as of Rails 2.3 is here: http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/singleton_class.rb

Answer (score 2):

Well, on my computer, you get a NoMethodError because the String class doesn't have a `class_eval` method :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that in vanilla Ruby, that is illegal.  For instance, if you try it in irb, you'll get a NoMethodError.

In a rails console, there might be extra methods added in that cause strings to behave like classes.